# React-Router: Always display a header but not in landing page

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

My current router tree looks like this:

```
  <Route exact path="/" component={Landing} />
  <Route component={Header} />§
  <Route path="/component1" component={Component1} />
  <Route path="/component2" component={Component2} />
  ...
```

I want to have the `<Header />` display always when rendering components `<Component1 />` and `<Component2 />` but not when a user is in the Landing page (`<Landing />`).

However, with the above react router tree, the `<Header />` is always displaying.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can make use of `Switch` from `react-router-dom` and configure your Routes like

```
<Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" component={Landing} />
    <Route component={Header} />
</Switch>
<Route path="/component1" component={Component1} />
<Route path="/component2" component={Component2} />
```

In the above case if `Landing` route matched, the `Header` is not rendered, else the `Header` is rendered